# SAX parsing - efficient way to get text nodes

Tags: java, xml, sax

Given this XML snippet

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
   <book id="bk101">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
```

In SAX, it is easy to get attribute values:

```
@Override
public void startElement (String uri, String localName,
              String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException{
    if(qName.equals("book")){
        String bookId = attributes.getValue("id");
        ...
    }
}
```

But to get the value of a text node, e.g. the value of the `<author>` tag, it is quite hard...

```
private StringBuffer curCharValue = new StringBuffer(1024);

@Override
public void startElement (String uri, String localName,
              String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
    if(qName.equals("author")){
        curCharValue.clear();
    }
}

@Override
public void characters (char ch[], int start, int length) throws SAXException
{
     //already synchronized
    curCharValue.append(char, start, length);
}

@Override
public void endElement (String uri, String localName, String qName)
throws SAXException
{
    if(qName.equals("author")){
        String author = curCharValue.toString();
    }
}
```

1. I'm not sure the above sample is even working, what do you think of this approach?
2. Is there a better way? (to get the text node's value)

Comment: it's the most efficient I think...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's the usual way to do it with SAX.

Just beware that `characters()` may be called more than once per tag. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1890404/sax-parsing-and-encoding/1891230#1891230) for more info. Here is a complete [example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/XML/SAXDemo.htm).

Otherwise you could give a try to [StAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/StAX).

Answer (score 1):

```
public void startElement(String strNamespaceURI, String strLocalName,
      String strQName, Attributes al) throws SAXException {
       if(strLocalName.equalsIgnoreCase("HIT"))
       {
            String output1 = al.getValue("NAME");
          //this will work but how can we parse if NAME="abc" only     ?
       }

   }
```