# Android XML parsing with SAX can't read after "&" mark

Tags: android, xml, saxparser

In my android application I read xml files and store those data in SQLite database. 
When I read a record that consists "&" mark it doesn't take entire text.

for example when I read the value in the following tag it only read the 49°38. The other part is loss.

`<latitude> 49°38&#039;59&#039;&#039;N </latitude>`

in the following instance it only take only get "John Levis" part and the characters after "&" are loss.

```
<name> John Levis & sons</name>
```

Does anyone have an idea to read the entire value ???

this is how I take the value from the XML handler class that extends the DefaultHandler.[this value take in the endElement methgod]

```
@Override
public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)throws SAXException 
{
    super.characters(ch, start, length);

    if(currentElement)
    {
        currentValue = new String(ch, start, length);
        currentElement = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1890404/sax-parsing-and-encoding/1891230#1891230

Answer (score 1):

The characters() callback in SAX is allowed to split a text node into as many small pieces as it likes. You should accumulate them and process them when you hit the end of the text (typically an endElement event, perhaps a startElement event in mixed content). Many parsers split the text when they hit an entity reference, but they are allowed to split it anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

& should be encoded as &amp; for the purposes of xml.  Could you add the header of your xml file so we can see the encoding?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>, this is header of the xml file

Comment: Have you used logcat in the default handler to see exactly what is going into the database?

Comment: Thanks AlaskanProgrammer... I found a way to parse XML using a string buffer. Matthew gave ma that...!!!